# Performing an AND query in elastic search

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

I have tried looking for another solution to this, but the `Bool query` in ES seems to not do quite what I am looking for. Or I am just not using it correctly.

In our current implementation of search we are trying to boost performance/reduce memory footprint of each query by changing our query logic.  Today, if you search for "The Red Ball" you may get back 5 million documents because ES returns any document that matches "the" OR "red" OR "ball" which means we get back WAAAAAY too many irrelevant documents (mostly because of the "the" term). I would like to change our query to instead use **AND** so ES would return only documents that match "the" AND "red" AND "ball".

I am using the `NEST Client` to do this with C# so an example using the client would be best since that seems to be where I cannot figure out what to do. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [query string query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-query-string-query.html) with `AND operator`.

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "default_field": "your_field", <--- remove this if you want to search on all fields
      "query": "the red ball",
      "default_operator": "AND"
    }
  }
}
```

or simply

```
{
  "query": {
    "query_string": {
      "query": "the AND red AND ball"
    }
  }
}
```

I do not know `C#`, but this is how it might look in `nest`(everyone,feel free to edit)

```
client.Search<your_index>(q => q
    .Query(qu => qu
    .QueryString(qs=>qs
        .OnField(x=>your_field).Query("the AND red AND ball")
        )
    )
);
```

Comment: Hmmm. Yeah I have been reading the docs on using the JSON API, but like I said the NEST client is how I have to query it and the NEST documentation is atrocious and completely under-documented. I will try that out

Comment: @MattHintzke For NEST 2.x, we are overhauling all of the documentation, using "literate" tests to include code examples with docs that remain in line with changes to the source - https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch-net/tree/master/docs/asciidoc

Answer (score 0):

I found the appropriate query to make using the NEST client:

```
SearchDescriptor<BackupEntitySearchDocument> desc = new SearchDescriptor<BackupEntitySearchDocument>();

desc.Query(qq => qq.MultiMatch(m => m.OnFields(_searchFields).Query(query).Operator(Operator.And)));

var searchResp = await _client.SearchAsync<BackupEntitySearchDocument>(desc).ConfigureAwait(false);
```

Where `_searchFields` is a `List<string>` containing the fields to match on and `query` is the term to search for.